# Sorcerer Spell Daily Limit in Simple Terms

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer

So the way it works, as I understand it, is at level 3 I have 5 level 0 spells(unlimited), and 2 Level 1 spells(6 times a day). What I need clarification on is do I get to cast each of my level 1's 6 times (making 12) or can I only cast any level 1 spell 6 times total?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a limit per spell-level, not per spell. The [sorcerer's **Spells** class feature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer#TOC-Spells) explains:

> Like other spellcasters, a sorcerer can cast only **a certain number of spells of each spell level** per day. Her base daily spell allotment is given on Table: Sorcerer.

So in one day, you can cast 6 1st-level spells, not 12. (Normally it's only 5 per day at 3rd level, according to the table, but you almost certainly have [a bonus spell due to your Charisma score](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Table:-Ability-Modifiers-and-Bonus-Spells).)